# Duplication of records due to Left Join

Tags: sql, join, left-join, right-to-left

I have 2 tables named Product Category, and Transactions. In Transaction Columns there are two columns called Transaction ID, and Product_category_code. In Product Category Table there are two columns called Product_category_code, and Product Name. I'm trying to combine the two tables by having the corresponding product name written next to the transaction ID. I'm using Left JOIN but somehow it is giving me same results as right join.

The code I'm using is:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Transactions] AS T1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Product category] AS T2
ON T1.prod_cat_code=T2.prod_cat_code
order by transaction_id desc
```

I'm getting 5 records for the first transaction after using left join when I should only be only getting one. How can I fix this?

First few entries of T1 is

[image]

First few entries of T2 is

[image]

First few entries of output is

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please add sample input and the expected output.  Your query looks fine, at least at face value, without knowing any data.

Comment: Just added more pictures.

Comment: Please _delete_ the images, replace them with _text_, and then also add the expected output based on the input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on both the category and sub-category codes